# How to consume an HTML Table using JQPlot?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I've been asked to evaluate JQPlot for possible integration with TrueFX such that a chart is created using JQPlot using the HTTP response provided for a given currency pair from TrueFX.  We are able to obtain HTML and CSV responses from TrueFX.

Question:  Has anyone setup JQPlot to use a CSV or HTML table as it's input?  Is there an alternative JQuery charting plugin that will better address our needs?

Thanks much for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand jQuery Visualize is designed for consuming HTML tables to make charts.

[Source](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/)
[jQuery Visualize Plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/)
*Download is near the bottom of the page.*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Do you know if this plugin has the ability to use the HTML table from a web service's HTTP response as it's input?  That is, the input values will be provided by the web service in the form of a table via HTTP response.  Thanks much:)

Comment: I am not 100%, as I haven't used it in that manner, however as it looks for a jQuery object representing an html table as input, you should be able to get it to work in the success callback of an ajax request with something like - 
[code]$(this).children('table').visualize();[/code]

Comment: Thanks much:)  I'm waffling between using Visualize and JQPlot.  Will play with both to see which one provides best results.

Comment: @SidC i know its been long but still want to know, what solution did you opt? i am facing the same problem :)

Comment: Visualize is neat, but isn't a real plotting library. I wrote the library mentioned below precisely because I liked Visualize's programming interface but the actual charting wasn't strong enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. My [Tablechart jQuery plugin](http://davideads.com/projects/tablechart/) consumes HTML tables and feeds them to jqPlot. It uses the table structure to construct series data and supports multiple column tables and multiple tables within the selector passed in.

I originally developed it for a project at Fermilab, but it seems to now mostly be used at newspapers. I most recently used it in a story [about crime trends](http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/local/chi-cta-crime-trends-20120622,0,3292937.htmlstory) on Chicago public transit.